# On Windows, can you use UNC like paths to files in PHP, for functions like file_get_contents(), etc?

Tags: php, unc

(Assuming the network folders/permissions are correctly set up and working in Windows, and a 'default' PHP setup...)

Is it possible to use UNC network paths [like `\\ServerName\Folder\file.txt`] in PHP's functions like `file_get_contents()`, `fopen()`, etc?

And/or, what special cases allow/disallow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNC paths should "**WORK**" if permissions are set properly. And the network folders are allowed to be accessed by apache user, then there won't be any problem.

In these scenarios **open_basedir** creates problems, just keep an eye on that

Comment: The script is not executed by the ftp server ;-) YOu mean the web/http server.

Comment: I mean apache user, my mistake VolkerK

Answer (score 0):

PHP absolutely permits UNC paths.  You may have issues regarding which user is actually executing the code.  If it is Apache running as a service then the user will be whatever user is listed in the entry for the windows service.  if it is IIS then the user is typically IUSR_machineName.  If it is as a console then it is the currently executing user.

Comment: In reference to Alex's statement about mapped network drives I do not recomment this.  Mapped network drives are not available to PHP applications that are running inside of a web server running as a service.  One application I have that requires use of mapped network drives is forced to run the web server as a console application (apache is in the startup and the server must always be logged in)

Answer (score 0):

No, `unc path` will not work with command, like @`exec` for example.

If you have a `php` script inside an `unc path` that calls `@exec`, it will failed, even if the `@exec` point to an executable in your c:\ directory.